# For a view based NSOutlineView, how can I make a checkbox to show only in the selected row?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have a view based NSOutlineView with, among other GUI elements, has a checkbox inside the Row view. I would like that checkbox to be hidden for all rows except the selected one. What I have tried so far is to bind the Hidden binding of the checkbox to "Table Cell View" with a key path of "superview", and I created a value transformer in which I receive a NSTableRowView as a value object, so that I can check its isSelected property. This works fine when the Outline is first displayed, but if I change the selection, always the first item's checkbox stays visible, while I would expect it to follow the selection dynamically.
Any help will be much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Binding to the view's ``superview`` isn't going to work because the binding is only going to update when the value of this property changes - whenever the view in question is given a new ``superview`` - since this has nothing to do with user-selection it's not the right approach. I'd consider making use of the selection delegate methods (specifically ``- (NSIndexSet *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:(NSIndexSet *)proposedSelectionIndexes``).

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul for pointing me in this direction ! the only thing I can say is that you have access to the new selection in the delegate method and you can hopefully make the desired checkbox visible, but I guess there is no way from there to know what the former selection was, so to hide that corresponding checkbox... Am I missing something ?

Comment: Both ``NSOutlineView`` and ``NSTreeController`` provide ``selectionIndexPaths`` bindings. The idea is that you create an array property in one of your classes and make this array the subject of this binding; whenever the selection changes, this array is automatically updated. If you add this array property to the class acting as the outline view's delegate, you'll have access to the selection whenever you need it.

Comment: Thanks again Paul... I have now in my mind your solution and I know I can spot the former and the new selection... How would you choose to have access to the rowView and its subviews so to hide one of the subviews upon selection change ? I am studying to solve this problem I hope I can get a solution but I guess your help could, again, point me in the right direction ! thanks, Alfonso